# Как занести в ipset все иностранные ip-адреса?

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, centos7

Пытаюсь запретить входящие запросы от других стран на сервер Centos 7 с помощью iptables. При этом планирую использовать ipset для создания такого списка. Неужели нужно заносить каждую сеть в список, например 32.87.45.0/24, или можно как-то сразу диапазоны  сетей занести в ipset? Как решить данную проблему быстро?

Comment: Блокируете по ASN, ипсет это может. База ASN есть на сайте Maxmind в свободном доступе, или в RIPN. Искать по тегу: `ipset + geoip`.

Comment: Не нашел как это сделать. Вы имеете в виду, что можно заносить asn в ipset? Можете подкинуть пример такой команды?

Comment: Можно, завтра кину, сейчас под рукой нет